# Slideup and slidedown box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big green box using `<div>`, and I have two more smaller divs called red and blue.

When someone clicks on green box, I want the red box to slide up at the same time blue box slides down.

And then when someone clicks on the green box, the red box should slide down and green box should slide up.

I have written this basic scripts, but when I click on the green box, both the red box and the green box will slide up at the same time.

How can make it so that one goes up and the other goes down at the same time?

CSS:

```
.block {
   position: absolute;
   left: 23px;
   top: 34px;
   width: 500px;
   height: 360px;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: #0F0;
}
.top-box {
   background-color: #F00;
   height: 179px;   width: 499px;
   z-index: 50;
}

.top-down {
   background-color: #00F;
   height: 179px;
   width: 499px;
   z-index: 50;
}

.bottom-box {
   background-color: #06F;
   height: 179px;
   width: 499px;
}

#red {
   position: absolute;
   left: 266px;
   top: 399px;
   width: 494px;
   height: 138px;
   z-index: 2;
}

#blue {
   position: absolute;
   left: 26px;
   top: 35px;
   width: 494px;
   height: 138px;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".block").click(
    function(){
       $(".top-box").slideUp('fast');
    },
    function(){
       $(".top-down").slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block">    
   testing on green
   <div class="top-box" id="red">
      <div class="top-down" id="blue">
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: SlideUp and SlideDown hides the matched elements with a sliding motion. Is that what you are after? Can you please post your code in jsfidde? So we can see what's going on...Thanks.

Comment: hi thanks for your response, here for you to see that sample but still not working in jsfidde, i'm new on that site, but not sure how to set with jquery in jsfidde. however please take look at that my jsfidde  http://jsfiddle.net/Alidad/TMTMH/1/  what i like to see that when you click on green box, the red box go slide up and blue box slide down both same time, how that works !

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide (by sliding up) a parent element and then expect the child element to be visible. Since `#blue` is a child of `#red` this isn't going to work. Also, since `#blue` is already visible, `slideDown()` won't do anything anyway.

Also, why are you passing two functions to [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)? `.click()` only takes one handler function. If you pass two arguments it will treat the first as event data.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned earlier, SlideUp and SlideDown hides the matched elements with a sliding motion. It will not "slide" things around.

I modified your code to create the effect using `animate` function. Have a look at the jsfiddle and see if this is what you are after?

[**http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/SRYXN/**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/SRYXN/)